# How do I get the index of items in a group

Tags: c#, linq

The code below gives me an Argument Out Of Range Exception. I am trying to get certain items of the current index with the ElementAt() exension method.  What am I missing here:

```
var orders = cart.GroupBy(x => x.ClientForOrdersId).Select
            ((x, i) =>
             new Client_InvoiceBalance()
                 {
                     IsMainClient = x.Key == x.ElementAt(i).MainClientId ? true : false,
                     MainClientId = x.ElementAt(i).MainClientId,
                     OtherClientId = x.ElementAt(i).ClientForOrdersId,
                     InvoiceOrderNumber = orderNumber,
                     IsPaidInFull = false
                 }).ToList();
```

Comment: The index in the `GroupBy(...).Select((x,i)=>` is the index of the group in all groups, not the index of the item in the group.

Comment: So is there a way to get access to the items?

Comment: please provide us with the structure of the ClientForOrdersId class, and explain what do you want to achieve

Comment: It's just a standard list of flat properties.

Comment: @user1206480: Do you want to create a `List<Client_IncvoiceBalance>` as result?

Comment: Tim, yes I do. I'm just simply trying to get access to the properties in the group via the index, but I'm obviously missing something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The index in the `GroupBy(...).Select((x,i)=>` is the index of the group in all groups, not the index of the item in the group.

Consider that there are 50 items in cart and your `GroupBy` creates 10 different groups according to their `ClientForOrdersId`.  Then the index starts with 0 and ends with 9. So you cannot use it in `ElementAt` because each group's size is only 5 and you get the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

I assume you want   to create a `List<Client_IncvoiceBalance>` as result. You don't need `ElementAt` at all but `SelectMany` on the groups.

```
List<Client_IncvoiceBalance> balances = cart
    .GroupBy(x => x.ClientForOrdersId)
    .SelectMany((g, iGroup) => // iGroup is the index of the group
        g.Select((x, iItem) => // iItem is the index of each item in the group
             new Client_InvoiceBalance()
             {
                 IsMainClient = g.Key == x.MainClientId,
                 MainClientId = x.MainClientId,
                 OtherClientId = x.ClientForOrdersId,
                 InvoiceOrderNumber = orderNumber,
                 IsPaidInFull = false
             }
        )).ToList();
```

Comment: That absolutely solved it. Never used SelectMany to now. Thanks for your time.